# Are fat drippings accounted for in the nutritional labels of meat?

Tags: nutrition

When I roast my chicken quarters, a ton of drippings come out.

The nutritional content is roughly 220 calories per 4 oz.

If I don't eat those drippings, does that mean that I am actually eating less than 220 calories for every 4 oz. of chicken quarters I eat?  I do eat the skin btw.

The fat portion of the drippings --as opposed to the stock portion--looks almost identical, and has the same consistency of cooking oil, and according to MyFitnessPal, has 115 calories per tablespoon.

So, if I eat 8 oz of chicken quarters, and this yields one tablespoon of chicken fat, this would be (220 kcal/4 oz * 2 - 115) 325 kcal net total?

Comment: Is it listed as raw calories or not?  If it is on the package then it will be raw calories of the contents.